# How to just use while() to print a message in case of an error?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am working on an exercise and I tried using while() to print a message when the input is other than present in the dictionary.

*Create a static dictionary with a number of users and with the following values:
First name
Last name
Email address
Password
Ask the user for:
**5.** Email address
**6.** Password

Loop (for()) through the dictionary and if (if()) the user is found print the following:
**7.** Hello, first name last name you have successfully logged in
**8.** Notify the user if the password and email address are wrong
**9.** Additional challenge: if you want the program to keep asking for a username and password when the combination is wrong, you will need a while() loop.*

```
# key and value
user_details = {
    1: {"first name":"carla","last name":"smith","email address":"carla11@gmail.com","password":"welcome1carla"},
    2: {"first name":"sandra","last name":"silva","email address":"sandra26@live.com","password":"welcome226sandra"},
    3: {"first name":"val","last name":"santos","email address":"val55@outlook.com","password":"332valwelcome"},
    4: {"first name":"suely","last name":"costa","email address":"suely41@yahoo.com","password":"suely8923"},
    5: {"first name":"sammy","last name":"vida","email address":"sammy32@hotmail.com","password":"vida323welcome"},
}

# ask user email address
user_email = raw_input("What is your email? ")
user_password = raw_input("What is your password? ")


#loop
for id,info in user_details.items():
    first_name = info["first name"]
    last_name = info["last name"]
    email = info["email address"]
    password_code = info["password"]
    
    if user_email + user_password == email + password_code:
        print("Hello, "+first_name+" "+last_name+ ", you have successfully logged in")
    while user_email + user_password != email + password_code:
        print("ERROR: the password and email address are wrong")
        print("Please try again")
```

Now the while print message keeps running non-stop. How can I print it just once, as requested in the exercise?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The `while` condition is never changed, so the loop will never break.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I tried adding an **if** in the while() but it still keep running the error message.                                                             `while user_email + user_password != email + password_code:
        print("ERROR: the password and email address are wrong")
        print("Please try again")
        if user_email + user_password == email + password_code:
            print("Hello, "+first_name+" "+last_name+ ", you have successfully logged in")`

Comment: @Suzane D there is no need of `while loop` there, you can simply check email & password using `if condition`

Comment: If you want to keep using `while` then use `break` after print statement

Comment: Is there a reason for you learning Python 2.X (i.e. from raw_input, but Python 2 no longer supported) rather than Python 3.x?

Comment: Oh the "break" thank you so much @PrashantMaurya!

Comment: @DarrylG Well...I just downloaded the Visual Studio Code, and when I tried with input, my code did not work....just with raw_input.

Comment: Seems you are in Python 2.X which is discouraged for new users to learn at this point.  You should make sure you're running Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the while to the right position. You are actually printing that the credentials are invalid indefinitly at the first invalid credential you find. Since you're stuck in the while loop you don't event look to the other credentials.

The way of doing it is :

1. Is there a successfull loggin attempt ? (No for the first iteration since there isn't a loggin attempt yet)
2. Supply credential
3. Test the credentials against the possible values

```py
# key and value
user_details = {
    1: {"first name":"carla","last name":"smith","email address":"carla11@gmail.com","password":"welcome1carla"},
    2: {"first name":"sandra","last name":"silva","email address":"sandra26@live.com","password":"welcome226sandra"},
    3: {"first name":"val","last name":"santos","email address":"val55@outlook.com","password":"332valwelcome"},
    4: {"first name":"suely","last name":"costa","email address":"suely41@yahoo.com","password":"suely8923"},
    5: {"first name":"sammy","last name":"vida","email address":"sammy32@hotmail.com","password":"vida323welcome"},
}

logged_in = False

#1. Is there a successfull loggin attempt ?
while not logged_in:
    
    #2. Supply credential
    user_email = raw_input("What is your email? ")
    user_password = raw_input("What is your password? ")


    #3. Test the credentials against the possible values 
    for id,info in user_details.items():
        first_name = info["first name"]
        last_name = info["last name"]
        email = info["email address"]
        password_code = info["password"]
    
        if user_email + user_password == email + password_code:
            print("Hello, "+first_name+" "+last_name+ ", you have successfully logged in")
            logged_in = True
        else:
            print("ERROR: the password and email address are wrong")
            print("Please try again")
```

Comment: Great Answer! If you dont mind could you please explain this part a bit further:

for id,info in user_details.items():
        first_name = info["first name"]
        last_name = info["last name"]
        email = info["email address"]
        password_code = info["password"]

I couldn't quite understand that!

Comment: The for loop will loop over the user_detail. The `.items()` allow to not loop over the value only but the key and value couple. So the key are stored in the id variable and the values in the info variable.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    The next part is just storing the differents values from the current value of user_detail in the first_name, last_name, email, password_code variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's enough to add asking for input in the while loop after the prints so the values for password and email change and the possibility appears for them to match:

```
# ask user email address
user_email = raw_input("What is your email? ")
user_password = raw_input("What is your password? ")


#loop
for id,info in user_details.items():
    first_name = info["first name"]
    last_name = info["last name"]
    email = info["email address"]
    password_code = info["password"]
    
    if user_email + user_password == email + password_code:
        print("Hello, "+first_name+" "+last_name+ ", you have successfully logged in")
    while user_email + user_password != email + password_code:
        print("ERROR: the password and email address are wrong")
        print("Please try again")
        user_email = raw_input("What is your email? ")
        user_password = raw_input("What is your password? ")
```